# Bit manipulation with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, bit-manipulation

I was trying to understand pointers better, especially with string literals. I wanted to print a letter's bits in a string literal.
My main simply contains:

```
char *a = "A";
showBits(a);
```

and the function looks like that:

```
void showBits(char *character) {
    int size = sizeof(char);
    const unsigned int maxPow = 1<<(size*8-1); // 128
    int j;
    int temp = -1;

    for(j=0;j<8;j++) {
        temp = (*character)&maxPow;
        printf("2%u", !!((*character)&maxPow));
        *character = *character << 1;
    }
 }
```

Obviously the code does not work. I could make the code work with `a[] = "A"` but that was not my intention, I wanted to work with pointers to understand them better. I wonder, if there is a way to make this work?

I could imagine, that you can extract the bits, when you simply right shift `maxPow` and do a logial comparison with `&`, but is there a way to do it/work with the pointer?

Also I was thinking of passing the address to the function by `showBits(&a)`, but can you then go through the addresses bit by bit?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: You're trying to write to read-only memory with `*character = *character << 1`. Copy the byte to a local first.

Comment: It's an odd approach, and confusing to read since you don't leave spaces around the bitwise AND `&` (which makes it look like address-of), but the reason it's not working is probably that you're trying to modify a character in a string literal (which is read-only).  Why not right-shift `maxPow` instead of left-shifting `*character`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment to `character` tries to modify a string literal which is not possible. When you change the code to  `char a[] = "A"`, a stack-allocated array is created which is initalized with 'A''\0' and can be modified.

As a rule, you should always use a `char const*` when using string literals. This would have prevented the issue completely. I think the compiler should have generated a warning.

I think you could just pass the char by value and then everything will work.

```
void showBits(char character) {
    const unsigned char maxPow = 128;
    int j;

    for(j=0;j<8;j++) {
        printf("%u", 0 != (character & maxPow) );
        character <<= 1;
    }
 }


int main()
{
  char const* a = "\127";
  showBits(*a);
}
```

I also simplified the function a bit because `sizeof(char)`is always 1 and removed some redundant code.

Comment: @MooingDuck I just copied the code from the question and did bother about correctness, just simplified it a little bit. The above now works, no need to use j in the loop :-) I tried to keep it as close as possible to the code in the question.

Comment: Upon rereading the code, yeah, you're fine.  I misunderstood it at first.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the most frequently asked question here (at least under C/C++).

Using `"A"`, you have an array of characters `"A\0"` allocated in a read-only memory segment within your program (typically in the RO data-section).

---

Every time a function declaring `char* a = "A"` is called, a local **variable** is allocated on the stack and initialized to point to the **address** of `"A\0"` in memory.

Since this variable points to a read-only memory segment, any attempt to change the pointed data is likely to yield a memory access violation during runtime.

---

Every time a function declaring `char a[] = "A"` is called, a local **array** is allocated on the stack and initialized with the **contents** of `"A\0"` in memory.

Since this array resides in a writable memory segment, the program can safely change its contents during runtime (as long as it doesn't exceed its boundaries).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do `*character = *character << 1` and bitops with `maxPow`, just print `(*character)&(1<<j)`.

```
int size_in_bits = sizeof(char)*8;
for(j=0;j<8;j++) {
        printf("2%u", !!((*character)&(1<<(size_in_bits - 1 - j));            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
void showBits(char *character) {
    char result[10];
    int mask = 0x80;

    for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
        result[7-j] = (mask & *character) ? '1' : '0';
        mask >>= 1;
    }
    result[8] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would divide the functionality into two functions:

```
void showBitsOne(unsigned char c, int bits_left)
{
   int bit = 0;
   if ( bits_left <= 0 )
   {
      return;
   }

   // Print the bit.
   bit = ((c & (1 << (bits_left-1))) == (1 << (bits_left-1)));
   printf("%d", bit);

   // Recurse.
   showBitsOne(c, bits_left - 1);
}

void showBits(const char *character) {
   while ( *character != '\0' )
   {
      showBitsOne(*character, CHAR_BIT);
      printf(" "); // Just add a space between characters.
      ++character;
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

With the following `main` function

```
int main()
{
   showBits("abcd");
   return 0;
}
```

I get the output:

```
01100001 01100010 01100011 01100100
```